# Gluon Afterburner Presenter.initialize() not called

Tags: gluon-mobile, afterburner.fx

Link to repository: https://gitlab.com/RichardGladman/medimindr

I've created a new Multiple view with Afterburner project using the IntelliJ plugin and added a new view to the project. It displays some about information as I thought it would be easy. The view displays just fine with the exception that the AboutPresenter doesn't get initialised meaning the AppBar is not populated.

The presenter class

```
package com.thefifthcontinent.medimindr.views;

... imports snipped ...

public class AboutPresenter extends GluonPresenter<MediMindr> {

    @FXML
    private View about;

    public void initialize() {
        about.showingProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                AppBar appBar = getApp().getAppBar();
                appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e ->
                        getApp().getDrawer().open()));
                appBar.setTitleText("About");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The creation in the AppViewManager

```
public static final AppView ABOUT_VIEW = view(
        bundle.getString("drawer.about"),
        AboutPresenter.class,
        MaterialDesignIcon.DASHBOARD,
        SHOW_IN_DRAWER);
```

I can't see a difference between what I have done and what was created with the project.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out they are still configured in the pom.xml. I thought it would be auto injection using Afterburner.